# How to create a page with links to other pages that include image and excerpt?

Tags: plugins, pages

I have several pages (not posts) on my Wordpress site. They contain excerpts (I forgot which plugin enabled that) and have an article image.

Now I would like to create another page that contains selected links to those pages. I would like to just select the pages and have those links created automatically with the excerpt text and the picture.

I found a plugin which does that, and it looks ok. It's just that the plugin is quite old and has not been updated for two years or so.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some alernatives.

First alternative is create a **taxonomy for pages** using [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Then, assuming this taxonomy is called 'pages-group' create a template file called `taxonomy-pages-group.php` and use [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to display your page as you want.

A second alternative is create a **shorcode** that you have to put into pages or post content.

Shortcode should look like:

```
[pages ids="12,23,34,45"]
```

You should register the shorcode with `add_shortcode` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)) function, something like

```
function add_pages_shortcode() {
  add_shortcode( 'pages' , 'show_pages_shortcode' );
}
add_action('wp_loaded','add_pages_shortcode');
```

And the create your `show_pages_shortcode` function that display the selected pages, something like:

```
function show_pages_shortcode( $atts = array() ) {
  if ( isset($atts['ids']) && ! empty($atts['ids']) ) {
    $pages = get_pages( array('include' => $atts['ids'] ));
    if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
      global $post;
      ob_start();
      foreach ( $pages as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <li>
          <a id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
          </a>
          <?php the_excerpt() ?>
        </li>
        <?php
      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
      return '<ul class="pages-list">' . ob_get_clean() . '</ul>';
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you can change the output as you want.

Comment: I've chosen the second alternative, and it works. Thank you very much! For completeness, the functions for image and excerpt are the_post_thumbnail and the_excerpt. As I said, I'm not that good in Wordpress or PHP. What I don't get is this: even though I placed the shortcode after some text on my page, the title, image and excerpt get displayed at the start of the page, before that text. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @nokul there was a bug in my function, I've corrected it. Try now.